# Issue command on multiple systems at once using MCollective

Tags: centos, command, mcollective

**Aim**

The aim is to execute a command on multiple systems at once using MCollective, e.g., `touch /tmp/helloworld` using MCollective-client creates `touch /tmp/helloworld` on all MCollective-servers: systems 1, 2 and 3.

**Attempts**

According [this documentation](https://github.com/puppetlabs/mcollective-shell-agent), mcollective-shell-agent could be used to accomplish the aim. However, executing:

```
mco rpc shell start ls -I /system/
```

results in:

```
Could not parse --arg ls
```

Issuing:

```
mco rpc shell --help
```

displays a general help menu instead of a specific menu regarding which arguments should be used.

**Questions**

1. Why does it not work to run the `mco rpc shell` command?
2. The assumption was that the `mcollective-shell-agent` should be used to accomplish the aim or is this incorrect? If true which package should be installed?

Comment: `^rpc^` (enter).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A [ticket](https://tickets.puppetlabs.com/browse/MCOP-423) was created and answered at PuppetLabs:

`mco rpc shell start command=ls -I /system/` should be issued instead of `mco rpc shell start ls -I /system/`